# $\tan(x), \cot(x)$ function properties

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Does $\tan(x)$ and $\cot(x)$ has symmetry axis? (like e.g  $\cos(x)$ at $\pi k$  for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$), I tried think in the direction that $\sin(x)/\cos(x) = \tan(x)$ and both of them have symmetry axis but I couldn't quite get around the solution.

Comment: First, velcome to our site!  What did you try to do? tell us!

Comment: kjetil b halvorsen he did...

Comment: Hi , thanks! the question was : did the funtion tan(x) ,cot(x) has a symmetry axis , I tried to look at the function graph and see if there is a symmetry, i think there isn't one but I'm not sure how to get the full picture, and a good explanation why this is true without relying only on the function graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Geometric approach**

Let's first look at the graphs of $\color{blue} \tan \color{blue}x$ and $\color{red} \cot \color{red} x$. (Note: the two graphs face each other in opposite directions)

[image]

Both tangent and cotangent have origin symmetry, and this means they are odd.

---

**Algebraic approach**

Foreknowledge: $\sin x$ is odd ($\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$), $\cos x$ is even ($\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$).

$\tan(-x)=\frac{\sin(-x)}{\cos(-x)}=\frac{-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=-\tan(x)$

$\cot(-x)=\frac{1}{\tan(-x)}=\frac{\cos(-x)}{\sin(-x)}=\frac{\cos(x)}{-\sin(x)}=-\cot(x)$

Comment: the origin is a point but i was asking about a symmetry axis (tha same as y axes in cos(x)), how can i expain y=tan(x) hasn't symmetry axis?

Comment: Try applying the following formula: $\tan(x-a)=\tan(x+a)$, where $a$ is the vertical symmetry axis. If this is true for $x\in\{\text{domain of }\tan x \}$, then $x=a$ is the symmetry axis.